# Javascript: how to load config at page initial without ajax request

Tags: javascript, http

In my single page application, I would like to load a sysCfg object with (tableName: [rows]) pairs into memory for future usage. This can be done by sending an AJAX request to the server at loading time, in the script included/embedded in the page. But a better way would be sending it together in the initial HTTP GET page respond and load to memory by the script to avoid the additional AJAX request. Not sure if there is a way to do this and how.

Answer (score 0):

If the data you desire to load can be represented as a JavaScript object, then just send it via a script tag in your above-the-fold content (maybe even the head, depending on urgency?). Now you have the data and a script to unpack it right there in the initial document as it is loading/parsing.

Comment: The sysCfg is generated at the server side by querying DB. If simply sending in the script tag, then it is shown in the page source in plan texts and much less secure. I think no one would do that.

Comment: Then I guess you’d have to examine the initial payload and find something you consider secure and attach it to that, or figure out a way to send it securely with the initial GET request as a separate resource. I’m running out of inspiration on this one, at the moment.